# Nginx dynamic route

Tags: nginx, dynamic-routing

I made a sample application that produces dynamic static files. I basically do not want to enter all the routes manually into the default file of `Nginx`. I saw some solutions here but the answers were not understandable for me in my simple case.

So basically my structure looks like this :

the main link of the application:

```
https://mysite.come/myproject/products
```

dynamic routes are numbers that also the link has query string
for example:

```
https://mysite.come/myproject/products/1?rand=something
https://mysite.come/myproject/products/2?rand=something
https://mysite.come/myproject/products/3?rand=something
https://mysite.come/myproject/products/4?rand=something
```

I could basically write :

```
 location /myproject/products/1/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/1;
   }
```

and need to repeat this for all the products which are none sense. Is there any way to do it automatically?

...

when I use dev mode ( npm run dev) I get

Answer (score 0):

maybe using try_files? see the last part of this [article](https://vocus.cc/article/630e3debfd897800015cd3fc)

Comment: I am not sure. First I need to write some the locations dynamically then move them to my localhost location

Comment: Instead of _just_ linking to a useful resource, add a summary of its key points in case the resource stops being hosted there in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /myproject/products/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   path_of_web_bundle;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work for me I think. Could I write something like:  
location ~/mysite.come/myproject/products/([1-9]+)  
and somehow in the body access to the argument [1-9]+ ?